# Можно ли назвать художественной династией братьев (больше никто - отцы-сыны - не упоминается)?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Творениями художественной династии Космати, воспитанников Византии,
>   полны средневековые храмы Рима.

Из следующего предложения нам ясно, что речь о братьях. И только.

Несколько далее:

> Потому Космати – не более чем прозвище, данное плеяде мастеров, по
>   одному из тех, точнее по тому единственному, кто имел привычку или
>   скорее, кому было позволено подписывать свои произведения – Cosma I
>   (но принадлежал он уже к четвёртому художественному поколению).

И пожалуйста, исправьте все ошибки.

Например, почему Р. п. у "воспитанников", что за туманная пунктуация во втором фрагменте и как выкрутиться с "данное плеяде мастеров, по одному из тех..." - речь же о единственном "подписанте", т. е. не имя, не кликуха какая, -

как быть-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Творениями (**представителе**й) художественной династии Космати, **воспитанников** Византии, полны средневековые храмы Рима.

Потому Космати – не более чем прозвище, данное плеяде мастеров **по одному из тех (точнее по тому единственному), кто имел привычку или, скорее, кому было позволено подписывать свои произведения  как *Cosma I*** (но принадлежал он уже к четвёртому художественному поколению).

Другой вариант: **по  тому единственному, кто имел привычку или, скорее, кому было позволено подписывать свои произведения...**

**Художественная династия  Космати:**  На протяжении двух столетий род Космати, к которому как бы приписаны были и их ученики... http://www.redov.ru/kulturologija/muratov_obrazy_italii/p239.php

Comment: "Художественная династия – это не обязательно родственники" ---Чем подтвеждена такая трактовка?

Comment: Трактовка исправлена.

Answer (score 1):

... **мастеров по имени того из них, кто имел привычку или, скорее, кому единственному было позволено подписывать**...

[Художественная династия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8) (если "династия художников" не подходит почему-л.)

Answer (score 1):

Спорно называть художников нескольких поколений *плеядой*. По определению, плеяда - группа, скопление, что подразумевает одновременное существование.

Comment: Спасибо, будем думать.